# Can we make a fixed navigation bar without css and only with html coding?

Tags: html, nav, navigationbar

I am doing some practical designs using HTML/HTML5. I am trying to design a navigation bar using html5 alone (not CSS or bootstrap or advanced techniques). I want to set up menus in the navigation bar. I am expecting navigation bar to look like something as mentioned in [the link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp) (With respect to size of each menu and how it covers the entire page).

I am using the below code inside body of HTML:

```
        <td colspan="3" width = 1200>
           <nav>
              <a href="index.htm">Home</a> |
              <a href="menu.htm">Menu</a> |
              <a href=" help.htm">Help</a> |
              <a href="order.htm">Orderss</a>
           </nav>

       </td>
```

I am getting navigation menu, but the font size is small and it is covering only 1/4th of the total page. I am expecting to cover at least 3/4th of the page (as mentioned in the link). I know, this can be easily achieved using CSS, but is there any way, I can achieve it using HTML alone?

Comment: Can you put the full code? ( full table )?

Comment: I just updated my full table code

Comment: You said, === it is covering only 1/4th of the total page === , What do you mean by total page? Is it with? or height? or both?

Comment: I mean width wise. The width is very small and even the font... If I try to increase the font by placing <h3> in front of Home or Menu, each menu is moving to next line in the web page.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done. You can consider HTML is just a structure of your website with some default style (also in CSS language), then we use CSS describes the presentation of an HTML.
We must use some CSS specific style to an element in HTML, e.g position: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

Try to add height attribute and percent value into `<td>` tag, for example for your navbar set the `<td>` height attribute to 25%, and for your `<td>` content set height to 75%

for example

```
<td height="25%">navbar</td>
<td height="75%">content</td>
```

Important : set the `body/html` height to 100%